# ARM linker ELF. Need a way to derive information

Tags: linker, arm

I'm Using ARM ADS tool chain to build elf and bin files. map file shows a function  0x20253025. In the elf file I see a branch instruction to the same function as BB,6D,E B,FF (4 bytes). BB is interpreted ad  so BB is fine.But the 24 bit address 6DEBFF does not correlate with @0x20253025. ANy idea where to look or how I can get the pattern?

Comment: Did you look in the ISA documentation?

Answer (score 2):

Branch instructions do not usually have the absolute target address:  they are encoded with relative offsets.  See [the branch instruction encoding](http://sourceware.org/cgen/gen-doc/arm-thumb-insn.html#insn-b).